# Rails has many through relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rails has_many through options and not sure if I am doing something wrong here. I would like for a player to create a season and when a player is about to create a season it will show a select menu of all the seasons I have created in years/new. So far that part has worked great but when a player try's to save the season rails does not save it. I am not sure if my association is correct or if I am doing something wrong? Is there any reason why this is not working?

error

```
No association found for name `season_year'. Has it been defined yet?
```

season.rb

```
class season < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :player

 has_many :quarters
 has_many :years , :through => :quarters

 attr_accessible :season_year_attributes
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :season_year 
end
```

quarter.rb

```
class Quarter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :year
  belongs_to :season
end
```

year.rb

```
class Year < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :season_year, :season_name

  has_many :quarters
  has_many :seasons, :through => :quarters 
end
```

player.rb

```
class player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :seasons, :through => :quarters
  has_many :years, :through => :quarters
end
```

_season-form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@season) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :season %>
    <%= f.text_field :season_name %>
  </div>

<%= f.fields_for :years do |year| %>
<%= select("season", "year_ids", Year.all.collect {|p| [ p.season_year, p.id ] }, { :include_blank => true }) %>
<% end %>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your models, I believe you need to change this:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :season_year
```

to this:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :years
```

When you accept nested attributes it is for a Model and not a property of a model (season_year is an attribute of the year model versus accepting the nested attributes for the actual model, Year).

EDIT:

In the Season model, I added year_ids to the attr_accessible expression:

```
attr_accessible :season_year_attributes, :year_ids
```

I also altered the season form so that the output of the select list for years was *only* this:

```
<%= select("season", "year_ids", Year.all.collect {|p| [ p.title, p.id ] }, { :include_blank => true }) %>
```

Comment: thanks did not notice that but it still does not save the selection that I have chosen?

Comment: You should be able to remove <%= f.fields_for :years do |year| %> because that would loop over the years associated with the selected season but the select() statement is collecting ALL years, regardless of their association. Back to the error ... When you save, do you get an error message?

Comment: I also added ":year_ids" to my attr_accessible statement in the Season model so that Rails would accept year_ids when I saved a season. When I did, it properly saved/updated my season.

Comment: I have removed the loop and have added :year_ids to my attr_accessible. Actually I think it works I just have to find out how to access it in my show view.

Comment: Good deal! In your view, it should be as straight-forward as: @season.years (and iterating over that array to output what you want).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any season_year in your Season class, that is the answer.

Did you intend to have this as an association?

Comment: I added season_year to seasons class and it gave me the same error just pluralized this time. season_year is the name of the field for the year form.